# Find the general solution of the differential equation of $\frac{dx}{dt} = x^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I used integration and arrived at the correct answer after a few attempts and with some doubts that I'm hoping to get some insight into:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = x^2$

$\frac{dx}{x^2} = dt$

$\int\frac{dx}{x^2} = \int dt$

$-\frac{1}{x} + C = t + C$

Here's where my doubt comes in. Why do the two constants, C, not cancel? That is, why is the answer not:

$x = -\frac{1}{t}$

Instead the correct answer is:

$x = -\frac{1}{t + C}$

Can anyone direct me to resources or provide an concise explanation on the rules for dealing with constants in cases like this one?

Also, how does the x become $x(t)$ in the final answer?

$x = -\frac{1}{t + C}$    becomes    $x(t) = -\frac{1}{t + C}$

Comment: You added _the same constant to both sides_. But there is nothing to say that this should be so. It should really be $$-1/x + c_{1} = t + c_{2}$$

Comment: The constants need not be the same, so we label them as, say, $C_1$ and $C_2$. Two constants can lump together to be another constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that we can't be sure in the equation $$-\frac{1}{x}+C_1=t+C_2$$ that $C_1=C_2$. So usually we proceed as follows $$-\frac{1}{x}+C_1=t+C_2\iff-\frac{1}{x}=t+C_2-C_1$$

Then since $C_2-C_1$ is also a constant, we just call it $C$ i.e. $$-\frac{1}{x}=t+C\implies x(t)=-\frac{1}{t+C}$$

To combat going through this thinking every time we solve a differential equation, we usually just add a $C$ after the integration to one side only: $$\frac{dx}{x^2}=dt\implies\int\frac{dx}{x^2}=\int dt\implies-\frac{1}{x}=t+C$$

Answer (score 0):

The constant of integration is the same. Do not label both constants the same way. However, the sum of two constants is a constant so you can label a third constant that is the sum of the two previous constants.
x(t) means that x is a function of t.